# Power Asking or Too many questions?

Tags: discussion

I've got an increasingly large list of questions that I'd like answers to that I think would benefit the community, but I don't want to be someone that's posting 10 questions in a row and hogging all the front page time.

Part of it is also that I want to push up our QPD on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4059/musical-practice-and-performance, but I feel that in this case I would be better to limit my rate of questions, would 1 Per day be a fair rate?

What do you guys think is the appropriate way to ask many questions, or the rate to ask them?

Comment: I join in the "raise QPD" movement. I think also there are important questions that have not been asked here yet. Maybe better than finding out the perfect day interval to post interesting questions, it can be every 10 questions the 11th is one from the "question list".

Comment: When I found out about the site, I had a few questions I'd always wanted to get answers to. I asked them all at once but did fear that it would be perceived as spammy...
I guess that we should be on the lookout for spam (or questions asked just to fish for rep) but remeber that new users may have years of questions bottled up in them.

Comment: I look forward to see your questions. We need more questions, but as Matthew said, it would be a good idea to spread out a bit, maybe a day apart (unless you keep piling up, then you need to get them off your hand..).

Comment: I've decided to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D-QD_HIfjA.  Unless I'm asking useless, redundant or already answered questions I don't see why not!

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend spacing them out a bit.  Not only for the reasons you mentioned, but also because you'll see a better response to them: getting different sets of eyes at different times.

When possible, it's best to ask questions as they occur to you.

Comment: The other reason being is that if you ask a bunch of largely unrelated questions at once, it doesn't seem like a problem you *actually* have and are just making stuff up.